# Booked an Entire Airbnb Apartment, got a private room only in shared ap

Tags: bookings, refunds, airbnb

I booked and payed 41$/night for an Entire Home/Apartment through [airbnb](/questions/tagged/airbnb), a total of 205$, plus 31$ Airbnb service fee (15% of the total).

I arrived and the guy told me without any realistic/emergency reason that he will be staying in the apartment too, but only during (some?) nights. Guess what? My girlfriend and I will be here only during nights too, since we are tourists, and some privacy would be nice (she doesn't feel comfortable already).

What are my options of getting a refund from him? I don't wish to nuke the entire thing and leave the apartment, and ruin my vacations.

He is willing to pay some money back (after me having to tell him to!), I just wonder how much money are "justified" to be payed back. The new entry in Airbnb is 27$/night, *but* if it wasn't for an entire apartment, I wouldn't have booked the room at all in the first place (it was our major criterion), which is something important.

Comment: Contact airbnb within 24h of checking in. They'll help solve your case and will even relocate if you ask.

Comment: I am closing this one as a duplicate since the answer to "I'm having problems with my airbnb booking" is always "contact airbnb".

Comment: I've booked last minute Airbnb. Leaving is always an option, then follow up immediately with the previous host and Airbnb asking for a refund.